Cypress intercepting
I'm trying to intercept a response. The interception in successful and when I log the intercepted response I can see in the log that the response is correct.
The problem is that this response is not loaded in the component.
I have a date-picker that has a placeholder that should receive a dateFormat value placeholder={date_format}. The value is changing after interception but it's not appearing in the placeholder.
Dose anyone has an idea why is this happening? Thanks
I tried
cy.wait("@getOrganizations").then((interception) => {
      cy.log("Organizations Response:", interception.response.body);
      expect(interception.response.body[0].date_format).to.equal("MM/DD/YYYY");
    });

and the log shows that the response is as expected.

What does your intercept function look like?

Thanks for your reply. I found an error in the logic itself
